# Actionbar Sherlock - tabs won't change in landscape when swiping

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager, landscape, android-tabs

I have a screen which uses ViewPager + actionbar Sherlock tabs. I have a `setOnPageChangeListener` set on the pager and it does the following:

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(final int position) {
    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
}
```

This works just fine in portrait mode and even in landscape if I only have few tabs and all the tabs are displayed. However if I add few more tabs in landscape, these collapse into a single drop-down widget. When I page through the ViewPager the `setSelectedNavigationItem` method is executed but now it has no effect on the drop-down selection: it stays at the last selected value. Which is really bad since user is missing a visual clue: tab may say "One" but user is already on page #6.

Is there a way to programmatically change which tab to display based on the position?

P.S. I know why this happens:
Here's code from com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl:

```
public void setSelectedNavigationItem(int position) {
    switch (mActionView.getNavigationMode()) {
    case NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS:
        selectTab(mTabs.get(position));
        break;
    case NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST:
        mActionView.setDropdownSelectedPosition(position);
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "setSelectedNavigationIndex not valid for current navigation mode");
    }
}
```

And when I step through that I can see that the navigation mode is still NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS though tabs are displayed as list. Now - my knee jerk reaction is to put code into onConfigurationChanged to set navigation mode appropriately but shouldn't this happen automatically?

P.P.S. And there's [Android bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38500) filed for it already that contains the patch

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Base on the Android bug I'm referencing in the question (see P.P.S.) here's workaround that indeed works. Just add it to your pager

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener()
     {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position)
        {
           actionBar.getTabAt(position).select();
           ViewParent root = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getParent();
           findAndUpdateSpinner(root, position);
        }

        /**
         * Searches the view hierarchy excluding the content view 
         * for a possible Spinner in the ActionBar. 
         * 
         * @param root The parent of the content view
         * @param position The position that should be selected
         * @return if the spinner was found and adjusted
         */
        private boolean findAndUpdateSpinner(Object root, int position)
        {
           if (root instanceof android.widget.Spinner)
           {
              // Found the Spinner
              Spinner spinner = (Spinner) root;
              spinner.setSelection(position);
              return true;
           }
           else if (root instanceof ViewGroup)
           {
              ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) root;
              if (group.getId() != android.R.id.content)
              {
                 // Found a container that isn't the container holding our screen layout
                 for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++)
                 {
                    if (findAndUpdateSpinner(group.getChildAt(i), position))
                    {
                       // Found and done searching the View tree
                       return true;
                    }
                 }
              }
           }
           // Nothing found
           return false;
        }
     });
```

Comment: this solution works for the native ActionBar but doesn't work for the compatibility one (on a Gingerbread emulator). how can this be fixed as well ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some code in the ActionBarSherlock library project in file ( ActionBarImpl.java ) see [this link](https://github.com/path/ActionBarSherlock/commit/5c0d48dec7c606502e34dbeb5abb283de636b443)

Comment: The fix you pointed to doesn't work, I just checked it. The code is only called from onConfigurationChanged and but I need selected tab changed when I swipe from page to page

Comment: If you are  using ViewPager than inside its listener you need to explicitly set the selected tab ... This is what I do in one of my project.