# ActiobarSherlock onConfigurationChanged Tabs Issue - Follow-Up

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, onconfigurationchanged

I have implemented the solution of the first ANSWER (by Amit), from this question:

[Actionbar Sherlock - tabs won't change in landscape when swiping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716593/actionbar-sherlock-tabs-wont-change-in-landscape-when-swiping)

I have the exact same scenario.

I have it working and it's acceptable, but I have 1 small problem I would like to solve, in order to have it perfect.

When I change the orientation of the device the swipe gesture works fine and the proper tab is selected, but when I **CLICK/TAP** on the Tab itself it doesn't work (indeed, the action is "delayed" until I swipe, which makes both actions, the click at last). So if I click 5 times randomly on the tabs, and I make a swipe, all clicks will be "released".

This is certainly some sort of bug of the introduced solution.

My question is: **Does someone know a solution for this particular issue?**